# Assembly - Are those imports valid functions?

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, disassembly

When disassembling Portable Executables I realize that the import section often contains names like `__imp_GetPixel` instead of `GetPixel` directly (`GetPixel` is just an example here). Is there a reason why? Are they still referring to the same function? Is the `extrn` keyword in `idata` always referring to functions or can it also refer to constants?

Example file:
[image]

Now, in the picture above it is pretty straight forward that those imports are functions. But sometimes it is not that clear(that is why I asked if only functions get imported):

[image]

Comment: *__imp_func* this is variable, which hold pointer to *func*

Comment: In a PE file imports are a table of function pointers that will be resolved at load time. The code jumps to the location pointed to by that pointer. This is because libraries location in memory isn't known until load time.

Answer (score 1):

A PE image can import functions and data.